# How can I add a link to the text of a Switch widget?

Tags: android, android-switch

I am trying to make an `"Accept terms and conditions"` switch. I was able to add the link into the switch but the problem is that the link is also on the switch button so each time I press the button to accept the terms and conditions it carry me to the webpage.

I would like that only the text that is selected as link, will be the link.

Here is the code that I have now:

On **strings.xml**:

```
<string name="terms">Accept<a href="http://www.google.es">terms & conditions</a>.</string>
```

On **register.xml**:

```
<Switch
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/terms"
     android:id="@+id/registerSwitch"/>
```

On **Register.class**:

```
Switch terms = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.registerSwitch);
terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

How can I make that only the text `"terms & conditions"` will be the link and not the switch button?

Comment: you can try switch and TextView separate

Comment: Please follow the naming conventions. It should be RegistrationActivity instead of Register. See this page - https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md

Comment: @Sufian Thanks for the advice. Actually I have it as RegistrationActivity on my real project but when I translated it to English I put it only as Register here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Shyam I would prefer to do it only with a Switch element. If finally it is not possible I will do it with two elements. I hate this kind of workarounds on Android for every simple behaviour :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you display the text separately as a TextView and setOnClickListener on the TextView to open your link. Some what like this:

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/your_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/terms_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Accept terms &amp; conditions" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

In Activity

```
TextView termsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.terms_text);
    termsText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yoururl.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did not do it with two elements because I thought it could be some way to do it only with one element. I used `terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` instead of `onClick` event. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add android:linksClickable

```
<Switch
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/terms"
android:linksClickable="true"
android:id="@+id/registerSwitch"/>
```

Comment: This does not work. If I just add `android:linksClickable="true"` the effect is the same but if I delete the line `terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` and leave `android:linksClickable="true"` the switch button works well but the link stop work.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/swtch"
    android:text="@string/terms"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```

in strings.xml

```
<string name="terms">Accept <a href=""http://www.google.es">"http://www.google.es</a>terms &amp; conditions</string>
```

and finally in activity

```
Switch terms = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.registerSwitch);
terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: It does not work. It just focus on the switch but it also through you to the link when you press the switch button.

Comment: then you have to use **Textview** and **Switch** separate and make link to the **Textview**.